# Al usar Ionic en mi página web se desaparecen los scroll y no me permite ver contenido que normalmente se vería usando el scroll

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ionic

Estoy usando ionic para mi proyecto web. Sin embargo, al anexarlo a mi proyecto, las barras de desplazamiento (scroll) se desaparecen no permitiéndome acceder a contenido que queda "bloqueado". 
He intentado usar este CSS, pero me sigue bloqueando.
.row-table {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
Anexo imagen de referencia de cómo se ve, como notarán, los scroll no aparecen a pesar de que el contenido lo requiera, por decirlo de alguna forma. Estoy cargando ionic desde los enlaces CDN. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]